# How can I append information in an XML file using LINQ in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to write some information in an XML file, the structure should be:

```
<Scoreboard>
 <Match>
  <name>Dummy</name>
  <score>1234</score>
 </Match>
 <Match>
  <name>Sample</name>
  <score>4567</score>
 </Match>    
</Scoreboard>
```

The problem is that I'm only able to write one entry, if I insert another "Match" the old one gets overwritten.

For example, if I have:

```
<Scoreboard>
 <Match>
  <name>Dummy</name>
  <score>1234</score>
 </Match>
</Scoreboard>
```

And then I want to add another entry the old one will be deleted and I'll only have the new one, for example:

```
<Scoreboard>
 <Match>
  <name>Sample</name>
  <score>4567</score>
 </Match>
</Scoreboard>
```

I would know how can I write new entries without overwriting the old ones.

Here's my code:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
//If file doesn't exist, then create it.

            if (!isoStore.FileExists("scoreboard.xml"))
            {
                XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("Scoreboard"));

                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream =
                   new IsolatedStorageFileStream("scoreboard.xml", System.IO.FileMode.Create, isoStore))
                {
                    doc.Save(isoStream);
                }


            }
            else
            {
//Else open it and write a new element which is a child of Scoreboard
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("scoreboard.xml", System.IO.FileMode.Open, isoStore))
                {
                    XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load(isoStream);

                    var newElement = new XElement("Match",
                        new XElement("name", VarGlobal.Name),
                        new XElement("score", VarGlobal.Score));

                    doc1.Element("Scoreboard").Add(newElement);

                    Messaggio.Text = doc1.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: If the file exists, you're loading it and appending a new value - but then you're not saving it again. So I don't see how the file contents will be replaced at all...

Comment: But if I don't save It then why do I see the new value when I load it again? And how should I save it?

Comment: If you don't save it you *won't* see the new value. You just won't. I suspect the problem is in `isoStore.FileExists`. You should be able to see that by debugging.

Comment: if (!isoStore.FileExists("scoreboard.xml")) checks if the file doesn't exist and It works because the first time it creates the file and second time it goes to the "else" statement, I tested it.

Comment: And I DO see the new value, it overwrites the old one, I tested that too...

Comment: Well the code you've shown never saves the value after going into the `else` statement, so either you're misdiagnosing it, or you've actually got different code than you've shown us. There's no way the code you've shown us will go into the `else` statement *and* update the file. Just look at the code - the only thing you're doing with `isoStream` is *loading* the file, not saving it.

Comment: I tried adding doc1.Save(isoStream); after adding the element in the else statement but in this way my program throws an unhandled exception:  Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it. Line 2, position 17.

Comment: Yes, that's because you'd be saving to the *end* of the stream. You need to load the document, close the stream, add to the document and *then* save. But as I say, the code you've presented so far does *not* behave the way you've been describing, which makes it hard to help you.

Comment: Ok, I see... I'll try to find another way to do that... Thank you :).

Answer (score 1):

Using XmlSerializer would be more efficient in this case instead of manually pushing elements inside the xml. Model your scorecard object and use basic Serializer and Deserializer. Following example should work (assuming your operation method is called SaveXmlValue()).

```
public class Match
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Score { get; set; }
}

public class Scorecard
{
    public List<Match> Match { get; set; }
}

public static Scorecard DeSerialize(Stream strm)
{
    var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Scorecard));
    strm.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return (Scorecard)ser.Deserialize(strm);
}

public static string Serialize(Scorecard scores)
{
    var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Scorecard));
    using (var strm = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var writer = XmlWriter.Create(strm, new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true, Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8 });
        ser.Serialize(writer, scores);
        strm.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var bytes = new byte[strm.Length];
        strm.Read(bytes, 0, (int)strm.Length);
        return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
}

public void SaveXmlValue()
{
    Scorecard scores;
    if (isoStore.FileExists("scoreboard.xml"))
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream =
            new IsolatedStorageFileStream("scoreboard.xml", System.IO.FileMode.Open, isoStore))
        {
            scores = DeSerialize(isoStream);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Xml file doesn't exist, create new score card object
        scores = new Scorecard();
        scores.Match = new List<Match>();
    }

    scores.Match.Add(new Match() { Name = VarGlobal.Name, Score = VarGlobal.Score });

    var xml = Serialize(scores);
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream =
            new IsolatedStorageFileStream("scoreboard.xml", System.IO.FileMode.Create, isoStore))
    {
        var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
        isoStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you VERY much for your reply!! I only have one problem... When I try to compile it, it says: "Error 1 'System.Text.Encoding.GetString(byte[])' is not accessible because of the protection level." ... What am I doing wrong? Thanks again!

Comment: I have modified the code to support general version of GetString method. It should work for you now.